Creating derived AutoCAD files for ship steel plate design: Seeking advice on terminology and outsourcing
I apologize if this question is too specific, but I'm hoping for some guidance.
My father works in ship design, creating steel plate drawings using AutoCAD. As my dad got older, the man who did the work below his eyes was going bad, he was looking for assistance with certain tasks. As I'm unfamiliar with CAD and technical design, I'm reaching out on his behalf.
My father mentioned a process called "pairng" (though I'm unsure of the exact spelling or term). The task involves creating a "B file" from an existing "A file." I'm not certain about the industry-standard terminology for this process.
A: https://autode.sk/3NioB1a
B: https://autode.sk/3YhBPBH
My questions are:
What is the correct term for this type of file derivation in AutoCAD, particularly in the context of ship design?
Is this a common task that could be outsourced to a CAD professional?
Any insights or advice would be greatly appreciated. Thank you for your time and expertise.

I suggest you ask this also on boatdesign.net .  Post on the main design forum for best results. There is also a software sub forum. https://www.boatdesign.net/forums/boat-design/

@PhilSweet Thank you dude, I asked on the fverr with some cash..

This is indeed something a CAD professional can do- a real design pro will be able to produce whatever the fabrication pro needs. Vocabulary is not my strong suit but the B is describing a subset of A and the contours of it. Depending on the industry that a drafter is used to, one may need to give them more explanation. These days a program should be able to handle it (not that such a program exists...)- the lines are a function of the direction of the surface normals.

The links are no longer working
